# Using Tee-Object to output the result of a python script to both terminal and file

Tags: python, powershell, output

The problem is that I cannot record the output of my Python script using `Tee-Object` to both terminal and a file.

I have multiple files containing lines of data. I need to verify this data via an HTTP request to a server. There are 8 large files and given I expect this will take a day to run since I don't want to flood the server.

1. Importing file strings and running Python script is producing output to terminal. Completed as follows:

   ```
   $db = Import-Csv C:\Users\xxxx\documents\bunnies\foo.txt
   foreach ($i in $db.StringName) {
       & py -2.7 myscript.py -option $i
   }
   ```

   `$db` is the file. `$i` is the string (line) in the file. script prints to terminal.

   Since the output is going to be over several days, I need to know that it will be recorded. `Tee-Object` has not created a file after an hour of output.

   ```
   foreach ($i in $db.StringName) {
       & py -2.7 myscript.py -option $i
   } > Tee-Object -FilePath .../bunnyrabbit.txt
   ```
2. I assume that `> Tee-Object -FilePath .../bunnyrabbit.txt` appended should create the file immediately and write in an ongoing manner?

   I need to be able to check the output is okay as the program runs.

**Additional: filtering output**

The output per line of the script is simply "x is correct" or "x is incorrect". If I want to filter all the corrects into one file and the incorrects into another how to go about this?

My original plan was simply to re-read the output file in python and do it in a language I know.

Comment: `> Tee-Object` -> `| Tee-Object`, and you need to replace your `foreach` loop with a `ForEach-Object` b/c the former doesn't write to the pipeline.

Comment: HI thank you for being so quick. I have an error 'unexpected token 'in'' now: 
`foreach-object($i in $db.Email){& py -2.7 gxlu.py -s $i} | Tee-Object -....`

Comment: `ForEach-Object` is not a drop-in replacement for `foreach`. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29148462/1630171).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the `|` pipeline operator, not the `>` redirection operator.

Additionally, either move `Tee-Object` inside the `foreach` body and use the `-Append` switch, or change the script to use the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet instead of a loop statement [as suggested by Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124738/using-tee-object-to-output-the-result-of-a-python-script-to-both-terminal-and-fi/50124958#comment87267650_50124738):

```
$db = Import-Csv C:\Users\xxxx\documents\bunnies\foo.txt
foreach ($i in $db.StringName) {
    & py -2.7 myscript.py -option $i |Tee-Object -FilePath ..\bunnyrabbit.txt -Append
}
```

or

```
$db = Import-Csv C:\Users\xxxx\documents\bunnies\foo.txt
$db.StringName |ForEach-Object {
    & py -2.7 myscript.py -option $_ 
} |Tee-Object -FilePath ..\bunnyrabbit.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I am about to understand something fundamental about powershell that I never understood before:

Comment: What exactly is the object? Some variable representing the line or the actual content of the line and how do you work it out for every cmdlet? The get-member property isn't quite the same thing.  The help files are really bad on for each! I didn't even understand the scripting guy posts about it.

Comment: The "object" in question is whatever `ForEach-Object` receives as pipeline input - if the expression `$db.StringName` results in an array of say, 5 strings, then the `ForEach-Object` scriptblock will execute 5 times, with `$_` referring to the current object in the pipeline each time. Does that make more sense?

Comment: [This might be helpful in understanding how cmdlets/functions in a pipeline behaves in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522415/are-the-cmdlets-in-a-pipeline-executing-in-parallel/48523475#48523475)

Comment: Yes it does. And thank you for taking the time. In order to access each string's content, would I need to use an object property like $_.Name or something, or is the actual object $_ the string? thank you ill check out the link. i really appreciate it!

Comment: That link is REALLY helpful thank you Anyone needing help on objects go to that link. Pipelines process concurrently.

Comment: `$_` is whatever you piped in - since you're already passing bare strings, `$_` will be a string, yes :)

Comment: Thank you Mathias. Please allow me a favour.Could you up vote me somewhere? I have another question ban!! It's like they are shooting the ones that can't keep up !