# How to recursively append to file name in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have multiple .txt files in folders/their sub-folders.

I want to append _old to their file names.

I tried:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '.txt','_old.txt' }
```

This results in:

1. Some files get updated correctly
2. Some files get updated incorrectly - they get _old twice - example: `.._old_old.txt`
3. There are few errors: `Rename-Item : Source and destination path must be different.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent already renamed files from accidentally *reentering* the file enumeration and therefore getting renamed *multiple* times, **enclose your `Get-ChildItem` call in `()`**, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), which **ensures that all output is collected *first***<sup>[1]</sup>, before sending the results through the pipeline:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse) |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace '\.txt$', '_old.txt' }
```

Note that I've used `\.txt$` as the regex<sup>[2]</sup>, so as to ensure that only a literal `.` (`\.`) followed by string `txt` at the *end* (`$`) of the file name is matched, so as to prevent false positives (e.g., a file named `Atxt.csv` or even a *directory* named `AtxtB` would accidentally match your original regex).

Note: The need to collect all `Get-ChildItem` output first arises from how the PowerShell pipeline fundamentally works: objects are (by default) sent to the pipeline *one by one*, and processed by a receiving command *as they're being received*. This means that, without `(...)` around `Get-ChildItem`,  `Rename-Item` starts renaming files before `Get-ChildItem` has finished enumerating files, which causes problems. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48523475/45375) for more information about how the PowerShell pipeline works.
<sup>Tip of the hat to [Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8507473/matthew) for suggesting inclusion of this information.</sup>

However, I suggest optimizing your command as follows:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter *.txt) | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName + '_old' + $_.Extension }
```

- `-File` limits the the output to files (doesn't also return *directories*).
- `-Filter` is the fastest way to limit results to a given wildcard pattern.
- `$_.BaseName + '_old' + $_.Extension` uses simple string concatenation via the sub-components of a file name.

  - An alternative is to stick with `-replace`:
    `$_.Name -replace '\.[^.]+$', '_old$&'`

Note that if you wanted to run this repeatedly and needed to exclude files renamed in a previous run, add `-Exclude *_old.txt` to the `Get-ChildItem` call.

---

<sup>[1] Due to a change in how `Get-ChildItem` is implemented in *PowerShell [Core] 6+* (it now internally sorts the results, which invariably requires collecting them all first), the `(...)` enclosure is no longer strictly *necessary*, but this could be considered an implementation detail, so for conceptual clarity it's better to continue to use `(...)`.</sup>

<sup>[2] PowerShell's [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) operates on *regexes* (regular expressions); it doesn't perform *literal* substring searches the way that the `[string]` type's `.Replace()` method does.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The below command will return ALL files from the current folder and sub-folders within the current directory the command is executed from.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse
```

Because of this you are also re-turning all the files you have already updated to have the _old suffix.

What you need to do is use the -Include -Exclude paramters of the Get-Childitem Cmdlet in order to ignore files that already have the _old suffix, and meet your include criteria, for example.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recure -Include "*.txt" -Exclude "*_old"
```

Then pipe the results into your re-name item command

Get-ChildItem cmdlet explanation can be found here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7

Comment: Good tip re excluding files already renamed from a _previous successful run_ (though you probably meant `-Exclude "*_old.txt"`). However, based on which answer the OP accepted, the problem was that the _initial_ run _didn't succeed_, due to already renamed files _interfering with the ongoing enumeration_ of files.