# Powershell Get-Content file not found after Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, filepath, get-childitem, non-breaking-characters, getcontent

I am currently trying to read the metadata from an index server export with PowerShell to be able to tag a SharePoint document library with this information.

First I search all XML files in the current directory:

```
$XMLPaths = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.xml
```

Afterwards I get data content from each XML file:

```
foreach($xmlFile in $xmlPaths) {
     [xml]$xmlData = Get-Content -LiteralPath $xmlFile.FullName
...
}
```

when executing the script I get the Error message **"There is no object in the specified path, or it was filtered by the parameters "-Include" or "-Exclude"**.

```
Get-Content : Im angegebenen Pfad C:\Users\...\1 Correspondence ZK12\2017\20170623 - CUSTOMER INVOICING - Re_ 
[Ticket#2017061510027357] [Ticket#2017061610029362] Invoice 80000066607 AF assistance March 17.msg.xml 
ist kein Objekt vorhanden, oder es wurde durch die Parameter "-Include" oder "-Exclude" gefiltert.
```

**Since this only occurs with .msg.xml-files, I assume it may be due to non-breaking space or similar chars in the filenames.**
Nevertheless, I am surprised that this information seems to be lost between the commands `Get-ChildItem` and `Get-Content`.

Any suggestions on how I could fix this problem?

Comment: What happens if you add `-LiteralPath <ThePathToSeachIN>` and switch `-File` to the Get-ChildItem cmdlet ? You also may need to add switch `-Force` to get items that otherwise can't be accessed by the user, such as hidden or system files.

Comment: It _may_ be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66227382/45375), though that `Get-Content` would behave this way with `-LiteralPath` is puzzling.

Comment: It could also be related to the path length (more then 260 characters?)

Comment: I would try `$xmlFile | Get-Content` which occasionally figures things out better, IMX. However, my guess is that either there's security blocking the file or the filenames are legitimately wrong in the input file.