# Rename files in a foreach loop with Powershell - Strange behaviour

Tags: powershell, loops, rename-item-cmdlet, foreach-object

I am renaming the files of a directory. The way to rename them is to add a letter to the beginning of the file name, depending on the option a user chooses ("F" or "O") A possible solution to this exercise is the following:

```
$Path="C:\app\SandBox\" 
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter *.xlsx | ForEach-Object {
        $opt = Read-Host "Do you want modify (F) this file or not (O)?"
        $name=$_.name
        $PathFinal=$Path+$name
        if ($opt -eq "F") {
           $newName="F"+$name
           Rename-Item -NewName $newName -Path $PathFinal
            } 
        if ($opt -eq "O") { 
           $newName="F"+$name
           Rename-Item -NewName $newName -Path $PathFinal
            } 
        }
```

The loop iterates as many times as there are files in the directory.
However, when I try to change the code as follows:

```
 $Path="C:\app\SandBox\" 
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter *.xlsx | ForEach-Object {
        $name=$_.name
        $opt = Read-Host "$name - Do you want modify (F) this file or not (O)?"
        if ($opt -eq "O") {
            $name=$_.Name
            Rename-Item -NewName "O$name" -Path $Path$name
            } 
        if ($opt -eq "F") { 
            $name=$_.Name
            Rename-Item -NewName "F$name" -Path $Path$name
            } 
        }
```

It turns out that, in some cases, the loop iterates one more time!
If I have two files in the folder, sometimes the loop oterates three.
Which may be due?

[image]

It should iterate twice, but iterate three. I can't think of what it could be due to, since when channeling it should pass only two files.

Comment: That is because the used filter also finds the files that have just been renamed. To overcome that, use brackets around the Get-ChildItem so it finishes enumerating the files first: `(Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter *.xlsx -File) | ForEach-Object {...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It should iterate twice, but iterate three. I can't think of what it could be due to, since when channeling it should pass only two files.

`Get-ChildItem` works against the file system by asking for the first file matching a given filter, and then it continues asking the OS "what's the next matching file name after `fileX`", until the OS says "no more files".

In this case, `A.xlsx` is renamed to `FA.xlsx` on the first iteration, and the OS is thus able to answer the question after the *next* iteration: "what's the next matching file name after `B.xlsx`" with "Next file is `FA.xlsx`".

To enumerate only the files already in the directory when you start the script, place the call to `Get-ChildItem` in a subexpression or nested pipeline:

```
$(Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter *.xlsx) | ForEach-Object { ... }
```

This will force PowerShell to wait for `Get-ChildItem` to finish executing before sending the first output item to `ForEach-Object` - and since `Get-ChildItem` is already "done" by the time the renaming starts, you don't risk seeing the same file multiple times.

Comment: Hum, in that case I don't understand how pipelines work.
It was my understanding that whatever is to the left of a pipe returns a result.
That result was sent via the pipeline, to the ForEach loop, in this case.
But, if I don't place the call to `Get-ChildItem` between `$(...)` , it will return differents answer via pipe in different iterations. Could be?

Comment: Another thing. If `Get-ChildItem` ask `Filesystem` "waht's the next matching file after `FA.xslx`" when `B.xslx` is renamed to `FB.xslx`, do not Filesystem answer `FB.xslx`?

Comment: @EduardoFernández Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522415/are-the-cmdlets-in-a-pipeline-executing-in-parallel) gives you a better idea of how pipelines are scheduled?